# Further data retrieving inside array of JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON file I want to fill in a table, but can't quite figure out how to retrieve the data inside and loop it through an array to get in a table I made.

This is my JSON file: test.JSON:

```
{
"data":{
 "Chair":{
    "id":24,"key":"Chair","name":"Chair","title":"oak home made"
 },
 "Table":{
    "id":37,"key":"Table","name":"Table","title":"round white table"
 },
 "Closet":{
    "id":18,"key":"Closet","name":"Closet","title":"big and red"
 },
 "Sofa":{
    "id":110,"key":"Sofa","name":"Sofa","title":"room for five persons"
 }
},
"type":"furniture","version":"1.1.0"
}
```

Then with PHP I used this: test.PHP:

```
$url = 'test.json';
$result=file_get_contents($url);
$decoded=json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($decoded);
```

This is what I get:

```
array(3) { ["data"]=> array(4) 
 { 
 ["Chair"]=> array(4) 
   { ["id"]=> int(24) ["key"]=> string(5) "Chair" ["name"]=> string(5) "Chair" ["title"]=> string(13) "oak home made" } 
 ["Table"]=> array(4) 
   { ["id"]=> int(37) ["key"]=> string(5) "Table" ["name"]=> string(5) "Table" ["title"]=> string(17) "round white table" } 
 ["Closet"]=> array(4) 
   { ["id"]=> int(18) ["key"]=> string(6) "Closet" ["name"]=> string(6) "Closet" ["title"]=> string(11) "big and red" } 
 ["Sofa"]=> array(4) 
   { ["id"]=> int(110) ["key"]=> string(4) "Sofa" ["name"]=> string(4) "Sofa" ["title"]=> string(21) "room for five persons" } 
 } 
 ["type"]=> string(9) "furniture" ["version"]=> string(5) "1.1.0" 
}
```

Then I am trying to retrieve "Chair", "Table", "Closet" and "Sofa", but I don't know how to do it. When I try this:

```
foreach ($decoded as $key => $value) {
 echo "key: ".$key;
 echo "</br></br>";
 echo "value: ".$value;
 echo "</br></br>";

 return;
}
```

I get:
key: data

value: Array

Can someone help me get "Chair", "Table", "Closet" and "Sofa", including each of thoses' id, key, name and title?

I have received guides, but they won't help me because I feel like this type of "array" is different then the links for guides I receive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping through the `array` on the top most level, while you want to be a level lower than that to be able to loop through all the `elements` of `data`, like this:

```
foreach ($summonerDecoded2['data'] as $key => $value)
{
   echo "key: ".$key."</br>";
   echo "value id: ".$value['id']."</br>";
   echo "value key: ".$value['key']."</br>";
   echo "value name: ".$value['name']."</br>";
   echo "value title: ".$value['title']."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
$url = 'test.json';
$result=file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);

foreach ( $decoded["data"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value[ "key" ];
    echo "<br />";

   //You can access data by:
   /*
    echo $value[ "id" ];
    echo $value[ "key" ];
    echo $value[ "name" ];
    echo $value[ "title" ];
   */
}
```

This will result to:

```
Chair
Table
Closet
Sofa
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)